# Multiple scripts access the same module with the same data in python?

Tags: python

Recently I have been trying to make a makeshift "disk space" reader. I made a library that stores values in a list "the disk" and when I subprocess a new script to write to the "disk" to see if the values change on the display nothing happens. I realized that any time you import a module the module sort of clones itself to only that script.

I want to be able to have scripts import the same module and so that if 1 script changes a value another script can see that value.

Here is my code for the "disk" system

```
import time
ram = []
space = 256000
lastspace = 0
for i in range(0,space + 1):
    ram.append('')

def read(location):
    try:
        if ram[int(location)] == '':
            return "ERR_NO_VALUE"
        else:
            return ram[int(location)]
    except:
        return "ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE"

def write(location, value):
    try:
        ram[int(location)] = value
    except:
        return "ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE"

def getcontents():
    contents = []
    for i in range(0, 256001):
        contents.append([str(i)+ '- ', ram[i]])
    return contents

def getrawcontents():
    contents = []
    for i in range(0, 256001):
        contents.append(ram[i])
    return contents

def erasechunk(beg, end):
    try:
        for i in range(int(beg), int(end) + 1):
            ram[i] = ''
    except:
        return "ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE"

def erase(location):
    ram[int(location)] = ''

def reset():
    ram = []
    times = space/51200
    tc = 0
    for i in range(0,round(times)):
        for x in range(0,51201):
            ram.append('')
            tc += 1
            print("Byte " + str(tc) + " of " + " Bytes")
        for a in range(0,100):
            print('\a', end='')

    return [len(ram), ' bytes']

def wipe():
    for i in range(0,256001):
        ram[i] = ''
    return "WIPED"

def getspace():
    x = 0
    for i in range(0,len(ram)):
        if ram[i] != "":
            x += 1
    return [x,256000]
```

Comment: The problem is in how you're calling this script, not in the script itself, please change it to show a Minimal example of where calling these functions cause you a problem? i.e. where you ` subprocess a new script to write to the "disk" `.   If you have two entirely independent .py files separately importing the above code, they will not be able to interact with each other in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest answer to your question, which I'm understanding as "if I `import` the same function into two (or more) Python namespaces, can they interact with each other?", is **no**. What actually happens when you `import` a module is that Python uses the source script to 'build' those functions in the namespace you're importing them to; there is no sense of permanence in "where the module came from" since that original module isn't actually running in a Python process anywhere! When you `import` those functions into multiple scripts, it's just going to create those pseudo-global variables (in your case `ram`) with the function you're importing.

Python `import` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

The whole page on Python's data model, including what `__globals__` means for functions and modules: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

## Explanation:

To go into a bit more depth, when you import any of the functions from this script (let's assume it's called 'disk.py'), you'll get an object in that function's `__globals__` dict called `ram`, which will indeed work as you expect for these functions *in your current namespace*:

```
from disk import read,write
write(13,'thing')
print(read(13)) #prints 'thing'
```

We might assume, since these functions are accurately accessing our `ram` object, that the `ram` object is being modified somehow in the namespace of the original script, which could then be accessed by a different script (a different Python process). Looking at the namespace of our current script using `dir()` might support that notion, since we only see `read` and `write`, and not `ram`. But the secret is that `ram` is hidden in those functions' `__globals__` dict (mentioned above), which is how the functions are interacting with `ram`:

```
from disk import read,write
print(type(write.__globals__['ram'])) #<class 'list'>
print(write.__globals__['ram'] is read.__globals__['ram']) #True
write(13,'thing')
print(read(13)) #'thing'
print(read.__globals__['ram'][13]) #'thing'
```

As you can see, `ram` actually is a variable defined in the namespace of our current Python process, hidden in the functions' `__globals__` dict, which is actually the exact same dictionary for any function imported from the same module; `read.__globals__ is write.__globals__` evaluates to True (even if you don't import them at the same time!).

So, to wrap it all up, `ram` is contained in the `__globals__` dict for the `disk` module, which is created separately in the namespace of each process you import into:

**Python interpreter #1:**

```
from disk import read,write
print(id(read.__globals__),id(write.__globals__)) #139775502955080 139775502955080
```

**Python interpreter #2:**

```
from disk import read,write
print(id(read.__globals__),id(write.__globals__)) #139797009773128 139797009773128
```

## Solution hint:

There are many approaches on how to do this practically that are beyond the scope of this answer, but I will suggest that `pickle` is the standard way to send objects between Python interpreters using files, and [has a really standard interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). You can just write, read, etc your `ram` object using a pickle file. To write:

```
import pickle
with open('./my_ram_file.pkl','wb') as ram_f:
    pickle.dump(ram,ram_f)
```

To read:

```
import pickle
with open('./my_ram_file.pkl','rb') as ram_f:
    ram = pickle.load(ram_f)
```

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense. I am going to try it.